# DRY project configuration in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm quite new to gradle, and I like this build system for its expressive power. However some things look quite tricky.

Consider the configuration code:

```
project(":A") {
    apply plugin: "X"
    apply plugin: "Y"

    someVar = "aa"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":C1")
        compile project(":C2")
        compile project(":C3")
    }
}

project(":B") {
    apply plugin: "X"
    apply plugin: "Z"

    someVar = "bb"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":C1")
        compile project(":C2")
    }
}
```

I want to make this config as DRY as possible. What I naively tried to do:

```
void myProjectType(someVarValue){
    apply plugin: "X"

    someVar = someVarValue

    dependencies {
        compile project(":C1")
        compile project(":C2")
    }
}

project(":A") {
    myProjectType("aa");

    apply plugin: "Y"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":C3")
    }
}

project(":B") {
    myProjectType("bb");

    apply plugin: "X"
}
```

Looks nice for me, but it doesn't work in gradle. Any suggestions, how to do it the right way?

---

If found the solution to half of the problem, which looks like this:

```
project(":A"){
...
apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle-config/config.gradle"
...
}
```

however such approach doesn't allow explicit parametrization of the 'applied' part (someVarValue as a parameter from previous example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of the `project` to the method - otherwise gradle won't know what is configured. So it will be:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
}

project(':A') {
    apply plugin: 'war'

    common(project, 'aa')

    dependencies {
        compile project(':C3')
    }
}

project(':B') {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    common(project, 'bb')
}

def common(p, value) {
  p.with {

    ext.someVar = value

    dependencies {
        compile project(':C1')
        compile project(':C2')
    }
  }
}

['A', 'B'].each { n ->
  configure(project(":$n")) { p ->
    task printVar << {
      println "project -> $p.name, var -> $someVar"
    }
    task printDeps << {
      p.configurations.compile.each { d ->
        println "project -> $p.name, dependency -> $d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Run `gradle printDeps printVar` to verify if it works correctly. Full demo is [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34557172). Feel free to ask in case of any questions.